# SwiftUI modifier .resizable() not available for Image

Tags: swift, swiftui

I found a lot of tutorials for SwiftUI where the modifier .resizable() is used on an Image.
It doesn't seem to be available anymore on Xcode 13.3.1 with Swift 5.

[image]

SwiftUI is imported. If you type the whole modifier myself is says

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It definitely is...

[image]

Have you definitely imported SwiftUI in that file?

If you type the whole thing out does it build or does it cause an error?

From the auto completion drop down it looks like Xcode thinks you’re referring to an `imageURL` perhaps there is a change that Xcode hasn’t caught up with yet.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect your questions.

Comment: @S.Gissel have you defined your own type called `Image` in your project?

Comment: No I did not. I deleted DerivedData. Helped nothing. If I use full qualifier SwiftUI.Image it works.

Comment: @S.Gissel that should only be required if you have another type called `Image` in your project. If you CMD-Click on the word `Image` and click "Jump to definition" where does it take you? (You'll have to remove the `SwiftUI.` bit first).

Comment: ohh I found it! In a well hidden autocreated struct from a JSON a Image struct is definied. I should have come up with "Jump to definition" myself. Sorry for keep all people busy with my flaws.

Comment: Haha, no worries. Glad you were able to find it :D Also... I'd avoid using anything auto created until you're more familiar with doing it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `Image` you are getting is from some other module (not SwiftUI).

If you are 100% sure you don't have another import -- then I recommend exiting Xcode and deleting derived data.

`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`

Answer (score 1):

Local module defines have a preference over system. Taking into account context menu proposals it is your case.

The fix is to use module explicitly, like

```
SwiftUI.Image("myImage").resizable()
```

Comment: ohh I found it! In a well hidden autocreated struct from a JSON a Image struct is definied. Sorry for keep people busy with my flaws.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a different `Image`, it's not from SwiftUI. See the color of Image is lite green(ies). You might be using an Image extension or something. Make sure while typing Image..., you select Image from SwiftUI.

Comment: ohh I found it! In a well hidden autocreated struct from a JSON a Image struct is definied. Sorry for keep people busy with my flaws.